# xampp not working on windows 7 - Windows 7 Forums

Tags: xampp

My xampp installation 1.7.4 in windows 7 does not seem to work. http://localhost returns not found error.

Xampp Control panel shows both mysql & apache service running fine.

Frustrated since past 2 weeks to find a solution to this. Any pointers and support will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your apache config? Both the ServerRoot and the DocumentRoot attributes in the httpd.conf file need to point at the right directories for things to work.

Comment: ServerRoot "/xampp/apache" and DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs" it is right..

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference for your case, but I am defining those attributes with this format:  ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache/"  -- only difference is I'm specifying the drive letter. See if that helps.

Comment: If you are getting a `404 not found` error, you probably have misplaced `index.html` or are missing it all together.

Comment: Refer this url:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939510/xampp-on-windows-7-not-working-properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have Skype or something similar running on your computer? Skype uses the default http and https ports 80 and 443 unless you explicitly change that in its settings.

Answer (score 1):

As I saw this is common "problem" for Windows 7 and Vista - in some cases these systems doesn't know 'localhost'. Try use http://127.0.0.1 or add one line to file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
This line is:

127.0.0.1             localhost

Answer (score 0):

Did you check firewall ? Or if you have broken windows firewall (which is sometimes it's not available to stop or even open firewall in windows 7), it may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

by default this link should work: ServerName http://localhost:80

at least it's in the http.conf this way. Check out if you have it the right way set (or to another port like 8080)

Answer (score 0):

Quit Skype, start xampp again, restart apache, run skype again. Now you can have both your apache server and Skype running fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In win7, you have a IIS running on port number 80 which is also default port for Apache server

Follow the Steps

```
1. Open httpd.conf in the conf folder of apache folder
2. Find Line "Listen 80" and change it to any other port say 8800
3. see if the file exists httpd.conf.build, if yes change in that too
4. restart the server and you are done

Do check all the app that uses internet and see what all app you have
installed uses port 80, in case the above steps don't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost uses the default port **80**. If you have changed it to **8080** in **httpd.conf**. Then you can also check it by using `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I had a similar problem and I described it here on my blog (NOTE: working Skype can be a issue but **I had *not* installed Skype then**):

http://paweln66.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/why-xampp-and-wampserver-doesnt-works-under-windows-7/

**There you can find:**

1. Explanation of possible reason why it does not work: **issue relates generally to Windows 7**
2. Two **approach to solution how you can enable XAMPP** "quick" and more advanced that not disable another services

Please read this post then everything should be clear!

I hope it help you...

Answer (score -2):

What if you use EasyPhp instead? i'm using it at work with windows 7, no problems, now xdebug works out of the box too