# localhost not found (xampp)

Tags: xampp, localhost

On a fresh install of Windows 7 and Xampp I am unable to access `localhost`. It just says not found even though Apache and MySQL are running just fine. What I tried so far:

- check the `hosts` file for this line: `127.0.0.1 localhost`
- check Skype (removed it completely).
- checked for anything else like Skype that could have caused a problem
- turned off virus scanner and firewall

I'm lost here, does anyone has a clue what the problem could be?

**[EDIT]**

I figured out the problem. For some reason Apache was using port `85` instead of `80`. I changed `Listen 85` to `Listen 80` in the config file from Apache. All is good now.

Comment: how you know that apache and mysql are running just fine ??

Comment: Control panel from xampp says they are running and i'm not getting any errors :x

Comment: have you turned off windows default firewall also ??

Comment: Yes thats the only firewall I use

Comment: Try using http://127.0.0.1 instead of localhost Also go through all answers for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665330/xampp-not-working-on-windows-7-windows-7-forums may be something will help

Comment: Add ::1             localhost   also to your hosts file in addition to 127.0.0.1  localhost. The former one is ipv6 convention

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This was not the problem however. I did find the solution, see my edited post.

Comment: you may post your edit part as an answer so that future visitors may get benefited..

Comment: teamviewer also uses port 80, uninstalling teamviewer solved my problem

Answer (score 21):

i faced the same problem. opening the localhost with specific port number is what resolves the problem. in my case i had changed the listen port to 8081 from default 80. So browsing http://localhost:8081 works well for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why in my previous XAMPP it was OK and it opened `locallhost` without any port number automatically but now we should add port number or type `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? Do you know how to change its setting such that it opens the right port automatically and not by typing?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this problem. Normally because of applications like Skype and VMware, we change the listening port of Apache from 80 to 81 or some other.

Then after starting apache, go to the web browser and type in localhost:XX

eg: if the port is 81, type in

localhost:81

Answer (score 2):

> Possible reason: A program is running with port 80!

*Run XAMPP (=> Apache) under an another port:*

**Rename** all ports with *80* to **8080** in your `httpd.conf` file.

*Your using Windows:* Use notpad or editor with `Ctrl+H` to replace "80".

> Well you correct it now to port 85. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

when you run Xampp, check the apache port no. ex: if it is displaying port 80, then type http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Xampp runs in port 80,443 by default and MySQL at 3306 There may be any other process running on the same port.

- You cannot run MySQL and XAMPP at the same time. (or MAMP)
- If you have Skype, kill the skype through the task manager
- Check which processes are running through port 3306

  Commands for your help

`netstat -ano | find "3306"`
`taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F`

It may seem silly but check whether you started apache server before starting MySQL.
Apache should be in run to open MySQL in localhost.