# MySQL Database won't start XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, xampp

I have updated my XAMPP version to 1.8.2. Now I have the problem that the MySQL Database-server won't start.

If I try to start the Apache Web Server (in 'Application manager'), it says "starting..." and after a few seconds it says "Running". When I do the same thing with the MySQL Database, it says "starting..." for a few seconds and then it says "Stopped".

When I look at the config file (my.cnf), I see this:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password           = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I think the problem is in the socket. mysql.sock does not exist in that directory and not even in the whole XAMPP-directory.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS: I have PHP 5.4 installed on OS X.

Comment: mysql will create the socket file if necessary, but only if that path actually exists...

Comment: possible duplicate of [xampp not working on windows 7 - Windows 7 Forums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665330/xampp-not-working-on-windows-7-windows-7-forums)

Comment: No it isn't the same. It only can't start MySQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had experienced the same error on Mac OS X (10.9) Mavericks i fixed by following these steps

1. Open terminal and use sudo su
2. Run ps aux | grep mysql
3. Kill all process using kill -9 PROCESS_ID
4. Start your MySQL using control panel

Comment: When I type kill -9 PROCESS_NO it says "kill: PROCESS_NO: arguments must be process or job IDs. what does that mean and how do I fix that?

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia it should be process no = process id

Comment: root             2536   0.0  0.0  2444636    100   ??  S    Thu09AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Anonymous.local.pid 

This is one of the result of my ps aux | grep mysql. which is my process id?

Answer (score 3):

Port 3306 might be used by other process, Can just change the Port number in Xampp mysql configuration and start the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience with xampp but I wasn't performing an update, this was a clean install.  I have had good luck running MAMP right out of the box.  This isn't exactly a direct answer to your problem, but if you just wanted to install something and get work done, MAMP could be an option.  I did a couple of hours of googling and I still haven't figured out the xampp issue here...